# Prove a Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone please explain what this means, and show how they equal each other?

$$L(u'_c (t)) = L(\delta(t−c))$$

Comment: What's $u_c(t)$?

Comment: @Isham, I think the OP should answer that. Besides the fact that $u(t)$ is not defined either. I mean, probably it's supposed to be a step function

Comment: Not any function sorry but Heaviside's function @YuriyS

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$
L\left[\frac{d}{dt}u_c(t)\right] = s\int_c^{\infty}e^{-s t}dt
$$

and

$$
L\left[\delta(t-c)\right] = e^{-sc}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: In looking at a laplace table it looks like u sub c is equal to e to the negative cs, all over s. The derivative of that would give a different answer. There must be something that I am not seeing.